# Does a Maven repository exist that can transparently build requested but missing local artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, repository

We are in the process of mavenizing our existing development process, and have found that it would make the logistics much simpler if our new internal Maven artifact repository could transparently trigger building missing internal artifacts.

In other words, developer needs to work on component A, which depends on our own component B, in release X.Y.Z and that artifact is for some reason not present in the repository.  We know, however, exactly how to build that release of B given the desired release number, and have a scriptable process in place for checking out the source and running `mvn install`.

My question is, is there any repository manager that can taught to trigger such a build when asked for B version X.Y.Z and return the newly created artifacts?

Comment: Odd requirement... Surely you only issue a new release of a component when there is something to be released.... That decision cannot be made externally to that component.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, consider what would happen if your local repository was accidentally deleted or pruned or similar things and you needed to repopulate it?

Comment: Your local Maven repository is merely a cache of artifacts downloaded from remote repositories. I regularily delete mine so that I can be sure that my build configuration is clean. Sorry the question continues to puzzle me.... If you know how to build "B" at version "X.Y.Z" then pre-build all the versions you need and upload them to Nexus

Answer (score 0):

Both Sonatype Nexus and JFrog Artifactory allow you to create custom plug-ins inside the repository manager that would probably be able to do this.

I've never done that but the docs describe how to do that. Maybe there are open source plug-ins available that do something similar you could use for inspiration :)

regards

werner